# Angular JS Using a Custom Provider in app.config/UI-Router onEnter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I would like to call a method on a provider in the onEnter event handler for a ui-router state.  I'm having trouble calling a method that is returned in the this.$get function.  I'm getting an error that the method is undefined.

The provider:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('my.module')
        .provider('mpSvc', function () {
            this.$get = function ($state) {
                return {
                    setBreakpoint: function () {
                        var currentState = $state.$current.self.name;
                        //other processing here
                    }
                }
            };

            this.myMethod = function() {
                console.log('Im defined but I cant access $state')
                console.log('$state is ', $state);
            }
        });
})();
```

The App Config:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui-router',
    'my.module'
])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', 'mpSvcProvider',
        function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, mpSvcProvider) {

            // Default route
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider
                .state('main', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'main/main-view.html',
                    controller: 'MainCtrl'
                })

                .state('main.some.other.state', {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: 'someurl/',
                    templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
                    controller: 'MyCtrl',
                    onEnter: function() {
                        console.log('enter mp');
                        mpSvcProvider.myMethod();  //this is visible
                        mpSvcProvider.setBreakpoint();  //this is not visible
                    }
                });
        }]);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was looking at the problem wrong.  By the time onEnter/onExit are fired we are actually no longer in the config code block, and the service can be targeted directed (san the "Provider" in the name).

e.g:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main.some.other.state', {
                        abstract: true,
                        url: 'someurl/',
                        templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
                        controller: 'MyCtrl',
                        onEnter: function(mpSvc) {
                            console.log('enter mp');
                            mpSvc.setBreakpoint();  //this is now visible
                        }
                    });
```